# LibGDX- removing items from screen on collision

Tags: android, libgdx

I am trying to remove items from the screen when they reach a certain height. My render method is below. All other parts of the code seem to work, but when the items get to the specified height, instead of removing them and rendering the next frame, an error is shown.

```
    batch.begin();
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    t = Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    time += t;
    speed = 300;

    if (time >= ((height / speed)/4)) {
        time = 0;
        onScreenQueue.add(spawnBlock(speed));
    }
    batch.draw(new TextureRegion(square.getTexture()),square.getPosX(), square.pos.y, padding, padding);

    for (Shapes i : onScreenQueue) {

        batch.draw(new TextureRegion(i.getTexture()), i.pos.x, i.pos.y -= speed * t, padding, padding);

        if (i.pos.y <= H) {
            if(i.getSide() == square.getSide()){
                onScreenQueue.remove(i);
            }
        }

    }
    batch.end();
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because you are removing items from a list, while iterating through it.
This results in a `ConcurrentModificationException`.
To avoid this, you might use an `Iterator`:

```
    for (Iterator<Shape> iterator = onScreenQueue.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        Shape i = iterator.next();
        batch.draw(new TextureRegion(i.getTexture()), i.pos.x, i.pos.y -= speed * t, padding, padding);

        if (i.pos.y <= H) {
            if(i.getSide() == square.getSide()){
                iterator.remove();
            }
        }
    }
```